# Jenkins Bitbucket Plugin - Cannot parse POST data

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Sending a POST request to `/jenkins/bitbucket-hook` causes a 500 error:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of`

Regardless of the content type, or body data.
The body data being sent is that outlined by Bitbucket:

```
{
    "canon_url": "https://bitbucket.org",
    "commits": [
        {
            "author": "marcus",
            "branch": "master",
            "files": [
                {
                    "file": "somefile.py",
                    "type": "modified"
                }
            ],
            "message": "Added some more things to somefile.py\n",
            "node": "620ade18607a",
            "parents": [
                "702c70160afc"
            ],
            "raw_author": "Marcus Bertrand <marcus@somedomain.com>",
            "raw_node": "620ade18607ac42d872b568bb92acaa9a28620e9",
            "revision": null,
            "size": -1,
            "timestamp": "2012-05-30 05:58:56",
            "utctimestamp": "2012-05-30 03:58:56+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "absolute_url": "/marcus/project-x/",
        "fork": false,
        "is_private": true,
        "name": "Project X",
        "owner": "marcus",
        "scm": "git",
        "slug": "project-x",
        "website": "https://atlassian.com/"
    },
    "user": "marcus"
}
```

Jenkins is the most up to date version, along with the Bitbucket plugin.

Update: I have used the data directly taken from BitBucket.
http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2015/05/20/sb/02.50.32555038623

Comment: *How* are you sending this to the endpoint? Are you doing this manually somehow, or are you seeing this error message somewhere when Bitbucket sends the webhooks?

Comment: is it enclosed into quotes?;) can you show please all the settings?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23681

Comment: @SiKing I have indeed. That is what prompted me to create this question, as clearly there is very little activity on that issue.

Comment: This is no help to you. :( I had a similar problem: http://serverfault.com/q/677933/278025

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have answered my own question.

For me to get rid of that error I just had to add a trailing slash to the url... Something so simple worked for me. Might be worth others trying it too.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Be sure to accept your answer and earn that rep!